# Missing .json files when publish web application project in .NET VS 2010

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, iis

I am publishing a web application project and outputtung to IIS Web Server. It's all going well as all the .vb code behind files are being well hidden. We have some .json file for configuration of some jquery controls we have and they are coimpletely vanishing. I wondered if anyone has encountered this problem and can give me some information on a possible resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open VS
Open Solution Explorer Tab
Click on the icon at the top of the tab to show all hidden files.
Find your file it should be set as not in the project 
click left or right button (i don't remember now) and choose add to project.
Rebuild your solution and now it will be saved into the right place.
When you upload file it will be into your compiled solution.

Let me know if it helps you.